# Add a new column in another df depending on informations in another df with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

He llo I have to tab file such as :

**file1.txt**

```
Seqname1 Seqname2
Seq1(+) SeqA
Seq2(-) SeqA
Seq3(+) SeqB
Seq2(-) SeqC
Seq8(-) SeqY
Seq8(-) SeqH
Seq10(+) SeqK
```

**file2.txt**

```
Clustername Names
Cluster1    SeqA
Cluster1    Seq1(+)
Cluster1    SeqC
Cluster1    Seq2(-)
Cluster1    Seq3(+)
Cluster1    SeqB
Cluster1    SeqG
Cluster2    Seq8(-)
Cluster2    SeqY
Cluster2    SeqH
Cluster3    Seq10(+)
Cluster3    SeqK
```

And the idea would be to first check in `file2.txt` for each element in `Names`, if this element has a `(+)` or a `(-)`,then check its corresponding `Clustername` and then go on the `file1.txt` and add at the column `Clustername` the corresponding `clustername`. 
Here for instance il `line 2` there is the Seq1(+), its Clustername is `Cluster1`, then I look for the line in `file1.txt` where `Seqname1` is present and I add `Cluster1` to the column Clustername.

So at the end I should get something like :

```
Clustername Seqname1 Seqname2
Cluster1 Seq1(+) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq3(+) SeqB
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqC
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqY
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqH
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqK
```

Does anyone have an idea using python and pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First read the files**

```
df1=pd.read_csv('your directory path/file1.txt', sep=" ")
df2=pd.read_csv('your directory path/file2.txt', sep=" ")
```

**Then,**

We can use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check rows that contains `(+)` or `(-)` . We can performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then we use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
m1=df2['Names'].str.contains('(+)',regex=False)
m2=df2['Names'].str.contains('(-)',regex=False)
new_df=df2[m1|m2].merge(df1,left_on='Names',right_on='Seqname1').drop('Names',axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Clustername  Seqname1 Seqname2
0    Cluster1   Seq1(+)     SeqA
1    Cluster1   Seq2(-)     SeqA
2    Cluster1   Seq2(-)     SeqC
3    Cluster1   Seq3(+)     SeqB
4    Cluster2   Seq8(-)     SeqY
5    Cluster2   Seq8(-)     SeqH
6    Cluster3  Seq10(+)     SeqK
```

Comment: i'm glad to help!

Comment: I have another issue with the same kind of problem. Maybe you will have the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038315/remove-lines-from-a-tab-file-according-to-content-in-another-tab-file-in-python

Comment: Done!! check it