# Remove lines from a tab file according to conditions in another tab file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

He llo I have two tab file such as :
**file1.txt**

```
Clustername Seqname1 Seqname2
Cluster1 Seq1(+) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq3(+) SeqB
Cluster1 Seq300(+) SeqB
Cluster1 Seq90(+) SeqL
Cluster1 Seq90(+) SeqO
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqC
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqY
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqH
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqP
Cluster2 Seq79(-) SeqY
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqK
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqS
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqT
Cluster4 Seq300(+) SeqB
```

**file2.txt**

```
Clustername Names
Cluster1    SeqA
Cluster1    Seq1(+)
Cluster1    SeqC
Cluster1    Seq2(-)
Cluster1    SeqO
Cluster1    Seq3(+)
Cluster1    Seq90(+)
Cluster1    SeqB
Cluster1    SeqG
Cluster2    Seq8(-)
Cluster2    SeqY
Cluster2    SeqH
Cluster3    Seq10(+)
Cluster3    SeqK
Cluster4    SeqB
Cluster4    Seq300(+)
```

as you can see in `file2.txt` **SeqL** is not present in the `Cluster1`, then I want to remove the line : 
`Cluster1 Seq90(+) SeqL` from the **file1.txt**

`Seq300(+)` is not present either in `Cluster1`, then I remove the line:

```
Cluster1 Seq300(+) SeqB
```

from the **file1.txt**

Same for:

```
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqP
Cluster2 Seq79(-) SeqY
```

there is no `SeqP` in `CLuster2` nor `Seq79(-)` in `Cluster2` in **file2.txt**, then I remove lines:

```
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqP
Cluster2 Seq79(-) SeqY
```

from the **file1.txt**

Same for:

```
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqS
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqT
```

because `SeqS` and `SeqT` are not in `Cluster2` in **file2.txt**, then I remove the two following lines from the **file1.txt**:

```
 Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqS
 Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqT
```

at the end I should get an ex file1.txt such as:

```
Clustername Seqname1 Seqname2
Cluster1 Seq1(+) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqA
Cluster1 Seq3(+) SeqB
Cluster1 Seq90(+) SeqO
Cluster1 Seq2(-) SeqC
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqY
Cluster2 Seq8(-) SeqH
Cluster3 Seq10(+) SeqK
Cluster4 Seq300(+) SeqB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to get the original columns:

```
new_df=( df1.merge(df2,left_on=['Clustername','Seqname1'],right_on=['Clustername','Names'])
            .merge(df2,left_on=['Clustername','Seqname2'],right_on=['Clustername','Names'])
            .reindex(columns=df1.columns))
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Clustername   Seqname1 Seqname2
0    Cluster1    Seq1(+)     SeqA
1    Cluster1    Seq2(-)     SeqA
2    Cluster1    Seq2(-)     SeqC
3    Cluster1    Seq3(+)     SeqB
4    Cluster1   Seq90(+)     SeqO
5    Cluster2    Seq8(-)     SeqY
6    Cluster2    Seq8(-)     SeqH
7    Cluster3   Seq10(+)     SeqK
8    Cluster4  Seq300(+)     SeqB
```

---

**Solution for n seqnames columns:**

```
df1['aux']=df1.groupby('Clustername').cumcount()

new_df= ( df1.melt(['Clustername','aux'],var_name='Seq')
             .merge(df2,left_on=['Clustername','value'],right_on=['Clustername','Names'])
             .groupby(['Clustername','aux'])
             .filter(lambda x: x.value.size>=(len(df1.columns)-2))
             .pivot_table(index=['Clustername','aux'],columns='Seq',values='value',aggfunc=''.join)
             .reset_index()
             .drop('aux',axis=1)
             .rename_axis(columns=None) )

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Clustername   Seqname1 Seqname2
0    Cluster1    Seq1(+)     SeqA
1    Cluster1    Seq2(-)     SeqA
2    Cluster1    Seq3(+)     SeqB
3    Cluster1   Seq90(+)     SeqO
4    Cluster1    Seq2(-)     SeqC
5    Cluster2    Seq8(-)     SeqY
6    Cluster2    Seq8(-)     SeqH
7    Cluster3   Seq10(+)     SeqK
8    Cluster4  Seq300(+)     SeqB
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a columns containing all necessary values
df1 is file1.txt, df2 is file2.txt

```
df1['cs1'] = df1['Clustername'] + ' ' + df1['Seqname1']
df1['cs2'] = df1['Clustername'] + ' ' + df1['Seqname2']

df2['seq2'] = df2['Names'][~df2['Names'].str.contains('(\()')]

df2['cs1'] = df2['Clustername'] + ' ' + df2['Names']
df2['cs2'] = df2['Clustername'] + ' ' + df2['seq2']
```

```
result = df1[(df1['cs1'].isin(df2['cs1'])) & (df1['cs2'].isin(df2['cs2']))]
```

filter the columns needed
`result[['Clustername', 'Seqname1', 'Seqname2']]`

```
   Clustername  Seqname1 Seqname2
0     Cluster1   Seq1(+)     SeqA
1     Cluster1   Seq2(-)     SeqA
2     Cluster1   Seq3(+)     SeqB
5     Cluster1  Seq90(+)     SeqO
6     Cluster1   Seq2(-)     SeqC
7     Cluster2   Seq8(-)     SeqY
8     Cluster2   Seq8(-)     SeqH
11    Cluster3  Seq10(+)     SeqK
12    Cluster4  Seq300(+)    SeqB
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct because it is not check within each Clustername.   So... for example Seq300 could appear in Cluster4 but you wouldn't would eliminate Seq300 from Cluster1 because you are checking the entire file not just with each clustername.

Comment: Can you add that case to your example for me to check my logic

Comment: @ksooklall I added it into the exemple

Comment: what is df2['seq2'] ?